# Retorno de consulta gerar Array

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Tenho uma consulta em MySQL.

```
foreach($resultado as $row)
{
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lon = $row['lon'];
$horario = $row['horario'];
}
```

Preciso que o resultado monte um array semelhante à este abaixo.

```
$markers = array(
array("latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon, "conteudo" => $horario),
array("latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon, "conteudo" => 'aaaaa'),
array("latitude" => -22.688211, "longitude" => -47.311065, "conteudo" => 
$horario),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário criar uma array antes do `foreach` e depois ir criando um [array multidimensional](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php#example-77).

```
<?php

$resultado = [
["lat" => 0.0,"lon" => 0.0,"horario" => "00:00",],
["lat" => 0.0,"lon" => 0.0,"horario" => "06:00",],
["lat" => 0.0,"lon" => 0.0,"horario" => "12:00",],
["lat" => 0.0,"lon" => 0.0,"horario" => "18:00",],
["lat" => 0.0,"lon" => 0.0,"horario" => "24:00",]];

$result = [];

foreach($resultado as $row)
{
    $result[] = [
        "latitude" => $row["lat"],
        "longitude" => $row["lon"],
        "conteudo" => $row["horario"]
    ];
}

var_export( $result );
```

[**Demonstração**](https://ideone.com/ySMsNN)

Comment: Obrigado, perfeito!!